# Using tmux through Cygwin: "open terminal failed: not a terminal"

Tags: cygwin, tmux

I'm trying to use tmux on a Windows Computer.  I successfully installed tmux using

```
apt-cyg install tmux
```

I can confirm successful installation because I get the following:

```
$ tmux -V
tmux 2.3
```

However, when I try to type "tmux" in the console, I get the following error:

> open terminal failed: not a terminal

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's your `TERM` environment variable set to?

Comment: as Console do you mean mintty or CMD ?

Comment: I don't think I have a TERM environment variable, and when I say "console" I mean cygwin (which I typed into CMD).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like the terminal you're using doesn't support full tty emulation. Clients like mintty (comes with Cygwin---or should, anyway), putty, rxvt for Windows, &c. will handle that. CMD, ConEmu, and Cmder won't.

There's not much to be done here without a huge ordeal (See second comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8577817). Unsatisfying though it may be, the best answer is to make sure you're running mintty. CYGWIN.bat should run it out of the box, so if that's not working, try running it directly from Explorer instead of from CMD. Otherwise, you might need to poke around in the batch file and make sure C:\Cygwin64\bin\mintty (or what have you) is being called.

Comment: Well, quite an old question and reply, but still not too old to comment with a concrete advice: I am using CygWin 3.3.6 on Windows 10. The CygWin setup provided a desktop shortcut, which starts a .bat Script, which in turn first changes to the installations "bin" directory and then starts "./bash --login -i". I changed the "Target" in the Desktop shortcut to "C:\cygwin336\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin.ico -" (including the trailing dash). With this change tmux starts without complaining.